# rmarkdown object not found using eval condition

Tags: object, import, r-markdown

I keep this error when I run the code below: Error in nrow(periodic_table) : object 'periodic_table' not found. I know my conditional is very simple but I just can't understand why it doesn't work but when I knit it it works. And also I found a turnaround for it but I don't' understand why the turnaround works

````
```{r}
download.file(url = "http://ismayc.github.io/periodic-table-data.csv", 
  destfile = "periodic-table-data.csv")
```
```{r}
periodic_table <- read.csv("periodic-table-data.csv",
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

```{r conditional_block, eval=nrow(periodic_table)>0, results="asis"}
cat("There are this many rows in this dataset,", nrow(periodic_table))

```
````

when I do this, it works:

````
```{r}
condition=nrow(periodic_table)>0
```

```{r conditional_block, eval=condition, results="asis"}
cat("There are this many rows in this dataset,", nrow(periodic_table))

```
````